# How to Load Balancing WSO2 API Manager without a load balancer?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have 2 servers. The first server has WSO2 APIM, BAM, BPS and GREG installed. These products are a MYSQL database. I would like to install APIM on the second server as well and utilize the same MYSQL database. How can I successful load balance the APIM without having a front-end load balancer? Is this a feasible solution?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly use computing resources of both of the physical servers you have to use a load balancer. If you are planning to use a software load balancer our recommendation is [Nginx](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/01/wso2-api-manager-scalable-deployment-patterns-part-2/://). Yes, you can utilize the same MySQL database server. When it comes to databases, there are some which can be shared among two API Manager instances. But you have to create few non-shared databases as well.

For more details about load balancing WSO2 API Manager, I would like to printout following articles.

1. [WSO2 API Manager Scalable Deployment Patterns - Part 2](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/01/wso2-api-manager-scalable-deployment-patterns-part-2/://)
2. [Clustering WSO2 ESB 4.9 with NginX](http://yasassriratnayake.blogspot.com/2015/08/clustering-wso2-esb-49-with-nginx.html)

If you need further help regarding this issue please let me know.

Thanks,

Upul

Comment: Thanks Upul for responding. I have installed nginx16 and I'm working through the configurations documented here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+the+Gateway. I only have 2 servers to configure the load balancing. Server 1 is where I installed nginx and I'm trying to also set it up as a Gateway Worker. Server 2 has API Manager with all components up and running. When I try to start the Gateway Worker on server one, it hangs on this last line ......APIKeyMgtServiceComponent started thrift key mgt service at port: 10397.......any ideas how the startup can get past this point?

Comment: Upul, I was able to get past this issue that turned out to not really be an issue. Apparently, the service just couldn't fully start up because I was missing a parameter in the startup script. I had: sh /wso2/wso2am-1.9.0/bin/wso2server.sh -Dprofile=gateway-worker. I appended "> server.out &" on the end and the service started successfully.